# Django-Jet "Page Not Found"

Tags: django, django-admin

I am attempting to install the [Django Jet dashboard](https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet), but I'm unable to get anywhere with it.

I've followed the [installation instructions](https://jet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), but no matter what I'm getting "Page Not Found" despite the URLs for Jet being listed.

[image]

There are a handful of Issues opened on this, but none offer a solution outside that it was resolved in newer versions, and I am using the recommended commit (latest).

**Issues:**

- https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet/issues/289
- https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet/issues/62

**Urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from depot import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('depot.urls')),
    path('', include('stores.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^jet/', include(('jet.urls', 'jet'))),
    re_path(r'^jet/dashboard/', include(('jet.dashboard.urls', 'jet-dashboard'))),  
    ]
```

I have no custom overriding admin templates. I have tried just visiting `/admin/`, but my admin looks like the default Django Admin (someone mentioned its supposed to take over the original admin templates).

**Installed Apps**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'depot',
    'stores',
    'jet',
    'jet.dashboard',
]
```

I have also verified I have `django.template.context_processors.request` under `Templates` in my **settings.py** as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is a super important note I missed. Simply moved `django.contrib.admin` to the bottom of my `INSTALLED_APPS` and this resolved this issue.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'depot',
    'stores',
    'jet',
    'jet.dashboard',
    'django.contrib.admin',
]
```